# Django: post_save signal and request object

Tags: django

Here two of my model classes:

```
class DashboardVersion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Dashboard name"),max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description/Comment"),null=True,blank=True)
    modifier = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False,related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modifier_related")
    modified = models.DateField(editable=False)

class Goal(models.Model):
    goal = models.TextField(_("Goal"))
    display_order = models.IntegerField(default=99999)
    dashboard_version = models.ForeignKey(DashboardVersion)
```

When a Goal is edited, added, deleted, etc., I want to change the DashboardVersion.modifier to the user who modified it and the DashboardVersion.modifed to the current date.

I am trying to implement this using signals. It seems though, that the post_save signal does not contain the `request`. Or can I get it from somewhere or do I have to create my own signal?

Or, should I do something completely different?

Thanks! :-)
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the most straightforward thing to do would be to just update the `DashboardVersion` in the view that processes the `Goal` update. If you have multiple views in the same module that handle `Goal` updates, you could factor out the `DashboardVersion` update logic into a separate function.

If you're dead set on using signals, you could probably hack something together with a thread locals middleware, but I'd say the simplest approach is usually best.

Comment: I am thinking that I override the save method on the Goal model to handle this there are 5 places where this update needs to happen. That is why I wanted to use a signal. However, I think overriding the save method should work too. Thanks for the options you gave! :)